# How to get data by mysql

Tags: mysql

I have list player as below.

```
+-----------+------------+------------+
| player_id | mission_id | reg_time   |
+-----------+------------+------------+
|         1 |          1 | 1508392600 |
|         1 |          2 | 1508392800 |
|         1 |          3 | 1508392900 |
|         1 |          4 | 1508392822 |
|         2 |          1 | 1508392500 |
|         2 |          2 | 1508392600 |
|         2 |          3 | 1508392900 |
|         3 |          1 | 1508392600 |
|         3 |          2 | 1508392600 |
|         3 |          3 | 1508392900 |
|         3 |          4 | 1508392900 |
|         4 |          1 | 1508392600 |
|         4 |          3 | 1508392900 |
+-----------+------------+------------+
```

I want to get all of player_id has

mission_id = 1, 2 and reg_time <= 1508392800 and

mission_id = 3, 4 and reg_time > 1508392800 as below

```
+-----------+------------+------------+
| player_id | mission_id | reg_time   |
+-----------+------------+------------+
|         1 |          1 | 1508392600 |
|         1 |          2 | 1508392800 |
|         1 |          3 | 1508392900 |
|         1 |          4 | 1508392822 |
|         3 |          1 | 1508392600 |
|         3 |          2 | 1508392600 |
|         3 |          3 | 1508392900 |
|         3 |          4 | 1508392900 |
+-----------+------------+------------+
```

How i can do by mysql?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-getting-started/en/#mysql-getting-started-basic-ops

Comment: You've mentioned all the conditions in your question itself. It's a matter of putting them into a WHERE clause with logical operators. Try it and if any failures in the SQL statement, post the statement here.

Comment: @Phan: are you rather asking for (mission_id = 1, 2 and reg_date <= 1508392800) OR (mission_id = 3, 4 and reg_date > 1508392800). Otherwise your condition AND  ing of mission_id = 1, 2 and mission_id = 3, 4 would give you empty result...

Comment: My code
SELECT * 
FROM player
WHERE (mission_id = 1 AND reg_time <= 1508392800) 
   AND (mission_id = 2 AND reg_time <= 1508392800) 
   AND (mission_id = 3 AND reg_time > 1508392800) 
   And (mission_id = 4 AND reg_time > 1508392800);
empty result
My expected 
|         1 |          1 | 1508392600 |
|         1 |          2 | 1508392800 |
|         1 |          3 | 1508392900 |
|         1 |          4 | 1508392822 |
|         3 |          1 | 1508392600 |
|         3 |          2 | 1508392600 |
|         3 |          3 | 1508392900 |
|         3 |          4 | 1508392900 |

Comment: @PhanChiHieu: why don't you have player id 4 in your result set above for both missions as they seem to satisfy your query...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this code to get your desired results.

```
SELECT * 
from `players` AS p 
where (exists (select * 
             from `players` as p1 
             where p1.player_id = p.player_id 
                   AND p1.mission_id = 1 AND p1.reg_time <= 1508392800 ) 
     AND exists (select * 
             from `players` as p2 
             where p2.player_id = p.player_id 
                   AND p2.mission_id = 2 AND p2.reg_time <= 1508392800)) 
AND (exists (select * 
             from `players` as p3 
             where p3.player_id = p.player_id 
                   AND p3.mission_id = 3 AND p3.reg_time > 1508392800) 
     AND exists (select * 
             from `players` as p4 
             where p4.player_id = p.player_id 
                   AND p4.mission_id = 4 AND p4.reg_time > 1508392800))
```

Comment: Where is `reg_date` column in the table provided and how can you get the query executed

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried your code but seem it isn't as my expected
my expected result like +-----------+------------+------------+
| player_id | mission_id | reg_time   |
+-----------+------------+------------+
|         1 |          1 | 1508392600 |
|         1 |          2 | 1508392800 |
|         1 |          3 | 1508392900 |
|         1 |          4 | 1508392822 |
|         3 |          1 | 1508392600 |
|         3 |          2 | 1508392600 |
|         3 |          3 | 1508392900 |
|         3 |          4 | 1508392900 |
+-----------+------------+------------+

Comment: @NareshKumar.P sorry will change it accordingly

Comment: @PhanChiHieu this will give you your desired output

Comment: @Miggy thanks but assume I need to get all players in 10000 records meet that condition. player_id = 1, 3 just my sample. I think player_id in () is not good

Comment: @PhanChiHieu if that's the case then my first query should be good. Let me get it back for you.

Comment: @Miggy your first query also get player_id = 2,4 but player_id = 2, 4 doesn't meet that condition (has both mission_id = 1, 2 and reg_time <= 1508392800 and
both mission_id = 3, 4 and reg_time > 1508392800)

Comment: @PhanChiHieu it does meet the condition. check carefully.

Comment: @Miggy thanks but player_id = 2 misses mission_id = 4, player_id 4 misses mission_id = 2,4. They don't meet the condition but your query show them in result

Comment: @PhanChiHieu i did try my best coming up with an answer for you. please check and i hope it helps. if it does you can mark it as an answer :). and BTW, in your sample data `player_id` = 2 must also be included because he has mission_id = 1 and 2 in the record with reg_time less than or equal than 1508392800. :)

Comment: @Miggy Thank you so much! I changed your query a bit then the result is ok as my expected

Comment: @PhanChiHieu glad to help :)

Comment: @PhanChiHieu ahh so thats what you meant! I'm gonna fix my answer for that! :)

Comment: @Miggy the result with your code is empty. You should fix it a bit! :)

Comment: what ahahhahaha. sorry my bad will fix again XD